# Print only lines with more than $1 words

Tags: linux, bash, wc

I'd like to print only the lines with $1 number of words or more. Please help.

```
while read line ; do
    echo $line | wc -w 
done t1.txt
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're defining a word as characters delimited by spaces, then awk would do this easily:

```
awk -v COUNT=$1 'NF>COUNT' t1.txt
```

It passes the first arg in as an awk variable named count, and prints rows where the number of space delimited fields is above the count provided.

e.g.

```
$ echo $COUNT
3
$ cat t1.txt
hey
hey hey hey hey hey
hey hey hey
hey hey hey
hey hey hey hey hey
hey hey hey hey hey
hey hey hey

$ awk -v COUNT=$COUNT 'NF>COUNT' t1.txt
hey hey hey hey hey
hey hey hey hey hey
hey hey hey hey hey
```

Comment: note that it's better to avoid all uppercase variable names due to potential conflict with build-in variables.

Comment: Thanks for the edits and the notes on variables.  Duly noted.  

FWIW, I left the print in there since without an understanding of it being the default action in awk the lack of it could be confusing and hinder the understanding of the implied conditional.

Comment: is it possible to have 2 arguments, for instance make it so it is bigger than $1 but less than 10

Comment: `NF>COUNT && NF<10`  - NF is the awk internal variable storing the number of fields.

Comment: @karakfa I understand it, I meant I left the print in there originally to show the asker what's happening, since he probably doesn't know awk.

Comment: that's not what I meant, not for you but for people not familiar with awk can read it as a filter applied to a file (records, input stream etc).

Answer (score 1):

Two things to remember when using a `while` construction.
1. Use `read -r`, not `read` to keep your input literally.
2. Keep external commands out of your body (like you have now).
When you want to process lines with `while` and an external utility, try to pull the external utility outside the while loop. In the `while` loop it will be called for every line, outside the loop it will be called only once. 
You would expect, that you should place the preprocessing chain of commands in front of the while loop:

```
cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3 | while read -r line; do
   echo "This ${line} has been preprocessed."
done
```

This solution has one big drawback. The while-loop is processed in a subprocess and any changes to variables set in the loop will be lost.

You can improve this by "process substitution":

```
while read -r line; do
   echo "This ${line} has been preprocessed."
done < <(cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3)
```

Now let's focus on `cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3`. How do you get the first 3 of `${n}` words from each line? You need to tune your command according to how you want to look to words. Is `word<space><space>word` a line with 2 words or a line with an empty second and a third word?
Play with different options to parse t1.txt:

```
awk # syntax not included here
grep ".* .* .*" # Difficult to use $n
grep -E "^(\w+ *){3,}" t1.txt
grep -E "^(\w+ *){$n,}" t1.txt
sed -n '/.* .* .*/p' t1.txt
```

The output of these commands can be redirected to the while loop, but for your basic requirements the while loop can be skipped.